# Problems with Angular OIDC Authentication

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth-2.0

I' read a few posts here on SO about angular-auth-oidc-client, also read the docs...but i can't figure out what is going on. I've been debugging this thing for days and can't still figure out the problem.

I'm building an YouTube Clone using an tutorial. So far so good, god the backend working, had a few difficulties with angular but i've come trough them. Now i reached the part where i should implement OAuth.

The tutorials says to use angular-oidc. Viewing the video and reading the docs i've got it implemented.

Problem is, when i try to login, i do receive an error in the console:

```
[ERROR] 0-(myclientId) - Error: no code in url
```

The error refers to the file app.comṕonent.ts, line 23. This where i call the checkAuth method. Looking the method from oidc, there's a parameter called url. But when i pass an url (backend or frontend) i do receive an different error. And also on the OIDC docs page there's no mention th pass an url, just call it and things should work.

This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  

  title = 'youtube-clone-ui';
  constructor(private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService){

  }


 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    
    
    this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuth().subscribe(({ isAuthenticated, userData, accessToken, idToken }) => {
      console.log(isAuthenticated)
    });
  }
  
  
  
}
```

And this is where my login method is, on the header of the page.
header.component.ts

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';
import { Globalcomponent } from 'src/global/global-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{
  isAuthenticated: string = ''
  
  

  constructor(private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.oidcSecurityService.isAuthenticated(this.isAuthenticated)
    
  }

  login() {
    
    console.log("login method")
    this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
  }
  logout() {
    console.log("logout")
    this.oidcSecurityService.logoff().subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
  }

}
```

The files are okay according to oidc documentation.  I've deployed them the following documentation directive and the tutorial.

When inspecting what is happening, i can see that it looks like i have a 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin' error. On the Networrk tab, checking the 'authorize' url, it returns a 302 error.

Request URL:
https://myurl/authorize?client_id=NJbox1ptzDdadd1Zo9mlBvtkElgge59v&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&nonce=316bfa513fdca032659144ae02ea9bb1f5R3q4mtu&state=ae998892fb321fdae6e13c9808005de0a0eHxeCi3&code_challenge=bQzQ47jYpAhb2ACE5D6ek9irF3N93dp02D06-1LjfT4&code_challenge_method=S256&audience=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F

Is there something i'm missing to debug this error? I'm kinda new to angular, but i can read the errors / code. And still can't figure out what does 'no code in url' means.

Also, here's my auth-config.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthModule, LogLevel } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';
import { GlobalComponents } from '../global/global-components';


@NgModule({
    imports: [AuthModule.forRoot({
        config: {
            authority: 'dev-i63rcznjs255jxgf.us.auth0.com',            
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,            
            redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
            clientId: 'NJbox1ptzDdadd1Zo9mlBvtkElgge59v',
            scope: 'openid profile offline_access',
            responseType: 'code',
            silentRenew: true,
            useRefreshToken: true,
            logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
            
            secureRoutes: ['http://localhost:8080/'],
            customParamsAuthRequest: {
                audience: 'http://localhost:8080/'
            }
        }
      })],
    exports: [AuthModule],
})
export class AuthConfigModule {}
```

That looks correct to me also (well, according to the documentation, it has been made correct).

Any input is appreciated. Any information that i might missed from type here, please inform me and i'll edit \ reply to the comment asap.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The error response says "service not found"

```
http://localhost:4200/?error=access_denied&error_description=Service%20not%20found:%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2F&state=ae998892fb321fdae6e13c9808005de0a0eHxeCi3
```